Tense after "I would think"/ "I would say" to give opinion

Context 1:

I and my are standing in a supermarket, we see and attractive man. Then I would like to make a guess:

Me: Do you see that man with nice outfit standing over there? I'd say
he IS/ WAS about fifty.
My friend: I would think so.


Context 2:We are looking at a dog.


Me: What kind of dog do you think he is?
My friend: I'd say he IS/ WAS a terrier.


Since you are speculating on the current age of the man and breed of a particular dog, again in the present, "I'd say that he IS …" is more accurate.
However in everyday conversation you are just as likely to hear ".. he WAS …"
In other words, both forms are equally likely in conversational English by native speakers, even though WAS is not strictly correct.
